# url property of background-image in css

Tags: css, url, background

I have a folder inside my ASP.NET web application. I put all css files inside 'App_Theme'. What is the right method to specify an image as background of a 'div' if I place image1.jpg inside "Icons/images" directory. The options for url are :-

1. **./Icons/jquery/image1.jpg**
2. **Icons/jquery/image1.jpg**
3. **/Icons/jquery/image1.jpg**

Which is correct ?

Comment: The background-image: URL("#foo.jpg), if used with a relative path, works relative to the CSS file. So if you have a CSS file as main.css in the styles directory and the image "image1.jpg" itself in the icons/jquery directory, than the URL will be "Icons/jquery/image1.jpg"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@muhammed; write this for image path
if your css in single folder

```
background-image: URL("../Icons/jquery/image1.jpg");
```

& if there is another folder inside of the main folder for example `stylesheet folder` & there is another folder inside it suppose `css folder` then we write

```
background-image: URL("../../Icons/jquery/image1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 5):

Go to your css file, right-click on the css class name > Build Style > Background > Browse the image. It'll put the URL in for you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually your file references in css are related to the actual path of the .css file. If you use /App_Theme/filename.css and you have /App_Theme/Icons/image1.jpg then you may wish to use url('Icons/image1.jpg');

Answer (score 0):

if you place images inside "Icons/images" then none of your options are correct as you are saying images can be found in /Icons/jquery/image1.jpg

what you need to do is specify the correct path, and it is ideal to use relative path to the root of your site.

/Icons/images/image1.jpg